# IOS Storyboard: How do I know what code controls what screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am a fairly experienced Android dev, teaching myself iOS, in android, you make a layout xml file for the user interface, and then you make a corresponding java class to control everything on that particular screen and manage transitions to other screens. This does not seem to be the way things work on iOS, for example, when I make a single view application from scratch, there are already ViewController.h and ViewController.m file there. But there is nothing in the code that relates those files to the view that is in the storyboard. And if I make another viewController, no new .h and .m files are created. The connection between the files and the storyboard screens is unclear, and that is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The UIViewController is linked to your class through the custom class option in the Storyboard inspector.

When you make a new UIViewController in the Storyboard, you will need to make a new custom class and link the UIViewController to your custom class by entering the name of your class in the Custom Class field in the inspector. Make sure you have the UIViewController in the Storyboard selected for the options in the picture to appear. Also make sure you are on the third tab as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The controller scene that you get with a single view application is typed to ViewController, so it goes with the .h and . m files that you get by default. When you make a new controller, you need to create a new view controller subclass, and then change the class of the controller in the storyboard to that class.